# mvc formsauthentication does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I use formsauthentication in my mvc application but it does not work as I expect. I have in my web.config file added ..

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/login/Login" timeout="30" defaultUrl="~/login/Login" />
</authentication>
```

But if I go directly to a page other than the login page, I still can view that page even if I have not logged on to the site. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you added the `[Authorize]` attribute to those controllers and/or methods you want to limit to logged in users?

Comment: Yes I have done that.

Comment: see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: DefaultUrl is the same as LoginUrl. Maybe, you are logged in and redirected to the DefaultUrl.

Comment: Its not working, I have the `[Authorize]` tag on my pages but if I add the `<deny users="?"/>` to my web.config file the login does not work. even if I enter correct login information I'm not transfered to the view I have set.

Comment: Thanks, the change of DefaultUrl made the login part work, but I am still able to access the restricted page if I enter that url directly even if I have the `[Authorize]` on the actions on that view.... do I need to add something more?

Comment: I got it working now, I had to remove the `<deny users="?"/>` part from the config file